# Cocos2d: graphics tool

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I started to learn Cocos2d to develop games and also Box2d; I read some tutorials and I seen that are used two couples of tool "LevelHelper-SpriteHelper" & "PhysicsEditor-TexturePacker".

I noticed that LevelHelper-SpriteHelper are more "simply" and organize levels and physics objects very well.
While with PhysicsEditor-TexturePacker I noticed some difficulties where the approach is not very clear.
So what are the best tools between "LevelHelper-SpriteHelper" & "PhysicsEditor-TexturePacker"?
And what are the differences? Can you explain me? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should answer your questions: http://abitofcode.com/2012/07/cocos2d-useful-tools/

Physics editor is a program that you use to create a tracing around a sprite that isn't a simple polygon. For example it could trace an image of a car, so that when you went to detect a collision between your car and another object with a physics engine (something like box2d) it registers a collision just with the car and not a square surrounding the car. Here is a picture that shows you what it does: http://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor/features.

Texture-packer is used to put all your sprites that you use in your game into one spritesheet. This allows you to minimize the amount of memory that all of your sprites take up.

http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker That picture shows you what it does. Instead of having to add all your individual sprite images to your game you put them all on a spritesheet, which trims the space around each image and puts it into a file size that cocos2d and the iphone can work with.

This is helpful because cocos2d only takes images that have dimensions to the power of two. (2,4,8,16....) If you had a sprite that was 50x50, it would actually take up 64x64 amount of space in your game.

Here is a tutorial that explains most of that better than i did: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2361/how-to-create-and-optimize-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d-with-texture-packer-and-pixel-formats

And here is project where both are used: http://www.raywenderlich.com/7261/monkey-jump

And here is one with levelhelper and spritehelper: http://www.raywenderlich.com/6929/how-to-make-a-game-like-jetpack-joyride-using-levelhelper-spritehelper-part-1

For a list of more tools go here"

http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/06/complete-list-cocos2d-tools/

Comment: in the link is not explained the differences, and the author say that PhysicsEditor is the only app that he don't have and don't use...

Comment: hope that is more thorough.

Answer (score 1):

SpriteHelper is essentially the same tool as TexturePacker. Both create a single large texture from individual images.

LevelHelper is an editing tool to design your game visually. It also allows editing of the physics world.

PhysicsEditor is a tool to create the (collision) shapes of physics bodies from images. No more, no less.